# Simplifying inverse trigonometric expressions such as $\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right)+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{x^2-1}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

Okay so I'm just looking for a short cut method or a method that is not so long for simplifying expressions like this

$$\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right)+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{x^2-1}\right)$$

Here is how I do it: I take the first term of the equation and convert it to $\tan^{-1}$ form, and then I apply the formula of $\tan^{-1}a +   \tan^{-1}b$. But this method is really time consuming; plus, it results in mistakes most of the times. Any alternatives or how you would do it, let me know, I'll be grateful. Thanking in anticipation.

**Edit.** Do I put $x= \tan y$ and solve? That should make it easy.

Comment: Okay what if something like this pops up?$sin^{-1}(1-x)-2sin^{-1}x=\frac{\pi}{2}$. How would you solve this?

Comment: To answer your last question: any real number $x$ may be written $\tan y$ for some $y\in]-\pi/2,\pi/2[$. Hence, you can safely replace $x$ by $\tan y$. Be careful though: $\arctan (\tan y)$ will be $y$ (with $y$ assumed to be in $]-\pi/2,\pi/2[$), but other expressions may be more tricky: for instance, $\arctan(\tan2y)$ is not always $2y$.

Comment: You may try to write $x=\tan y$ and consider four cases: $x<1$, $x\in]-1,0]$, $x\in [0,1[$ and $x>1$. It should simplify on each interval, but you will end up with a different expression for each interval. Plotting your function will certainly help you check you are in the right direction: [see WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+acos((x%5E2-1)%2F(x%5E2%2B1))%2Batan((2x)%2F(x%5E2-1))+for+x+from+-2+to+3)

Comment: The two wrong answers below should convince you tht it's not so easy, in general. Also, I don't understand your comment above: do you want to solve an equation (i.e., find $x$ such that it's true), or to prove that it's true for all $x$? Notice it's not true for all $x$: [WA, again](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+asin(1-x)-2*asin(x)+for+x+from+0+to+1).

Comment: And if it's an equation: compute the derivative and show it's negative (very easy), so your function is decreasing. Then, for $x=0$ you get $\sin^{-1}(1)+2\sin^{-1}(0)=\pi/2$, hence $x=0$ is a solution, and it's the only one.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\frac{1-\tan^2(u)}{1+\tan^2(u)}=\cos(2u)\implies
\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right)
=\left\{\begin{array}{}
\pi+2\tan^{-1}(x)&\text{if }x\lt0\\
\pi-2\tan^{-1}(x)&\text{if }x\gt0
\end{array}\right.
$$
$$
\frac{2\tan(u)}{1-\tan^2(u)}=\tan(2u)\implies
\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{x^2-1}\right)
=\left\{\begin{array}{}
-\pi-2\tan^{-1}(x)&\text{if }x\lt-1\\
-2\tan^{-1}(x)&\text{if }-1\lt x\lt1\\
\pi-2\tan^{-1}(x)&\text{if }x\gt1
\end{array}\right.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right)+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{x^2-1}\right)
=\left\{\begin{array}{}
0&\text{if }x\lt-1\\
\pi&\text{if }-1\lt x\le0\\
\pi-4\tan^{-1}(x)&\text{if }0\lt x\lt1\\
2\pi-4\tan^{-1}(x)&\text{if }x\gt1
\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: interesting, we came to the same conclusion

Answer (score 2):

### Revised for the last part

In your specific case 
$$
\cos ^{ - 1} \left( {\frac{{x^2  - 1}}
{{x^2  + 1}}} \right) + \tan ^{ - 1} \left( {\frac{{2x}}
{{x^2  - 1}}} \right)
$$
you may note that:
$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  x^2  - 1 = \operatorname{Re} \left( {\left( {x + i} \right)^2 } \right) \hfill \\
  2x = \operatorname{Im} \left( {\left( {x + i} \right)^2 } \right) \hfill \\
  \left( {x^2  + 1} \right) = \left| {\left( {x + i} \right)} \right|^2  = \left| {\left( {x + i} \right)^2 } \right| \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
so that
$$
\begin{gathered}
 f(x)= \cos ^{ - 1} \left( {\frac{{x^2  - 1}}
{{x^2  + 1}}} \right) + \tan ^{ - 1} \left( {\frac{{2x}}
{{x^2  - 1}}} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \cos ^{ - 1} \left( {\frac{{\operatorname{Re} \left( {\left( {x + i} \right)^2 } \right)}}
{{\left| {\left( {x + i} \right)^2 } \right|}}} \right) + \tan ^{ - 1} \left( {\frac{{\operatorname{Im} \left( {\left( {x + i} \right)^2 } \right)}}
{{\operatorname{Re} \left( {\left( {x + i} \right)^2 } \right)}}} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \cos ^{ - 1} \left( {\cos \left( {2\arg \left( {x + i} \right)} \right)} \right) + \tan ^{ - 1} \left( {\tan \left( {2\arg \left( {x + i} \right)} \right)} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
Here we have to stop and do some case distinction, because
of the codomain limitation in the definition of $arccos$ and $arctan$, which if overlooked will cause the error signalled by *Jean-Claude Arbaut*.
In fact
$$
\cos ^{ - 1} \left( {\cos \alpha } \right) = \left| {\alpha _ *  } \right|\quad \quad \tan ^{ - 1} \left( {\tan \alpha } \right) = \alpha _{\, *  * } \quad \left| {\;\alpha _{\, *  * }  \ne \pi /2} \right.
$$
where the star indices indicate the necessary reductions mod $2\pi$ and $\pi$, that is
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \alpha _{\, * }  = \pi  - \bmod \left( {\pi  - \alpha ,\;2\,\,\pi } \right)\quad \left| \; \right. - \pi  < \alpha _{\, * }  \leqslant \pi  \hfill \\
  \alpha _{\, *  * }  = \pi /2 - \bmod \left( {\pi /2 - \alpha ,\;\,\pi } \right)\quad \left| \; \right. - \,\pi /2 < \alpha _{\, *  * }  \leqslant \pi /2 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
So the development above continues as:
$$
\begin{gathered}
  f(x) = \cos ^{ - 1} \left( {\frac{{x^2  - 1}}
{{x^2  + 1}}} \right) + \tan ^{ - 1} \left( {\frac{{2x}}
{{x^2  - 1}}} \right)\quad \left| {\;x \ne 0,\; \pm 1} \right.\quad  =  \hfill \\
   = \cos ^{ - 1} \left( {\cos \left( {2\arg \left( {x + i} \right)} \right)} \right) + \tan ^{ - 1} \left( {\tan \left( {2\arg \left( {x + i} \right)} \right)} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \left| {\left( {2\arg \left( {x + i} \right)} \right)_ *  } \right| + \left( {2\arg \left( {x + i} \right)} \right)_{\, *  * }  =  \hfill \\
   = \left| {\left( {2\tan ^{ - 1} \left( {1/x} \right)} \right)_ *  } \right| + \left( {2\tan ^{ - 1} \left( {1/x} \right)} \right)_{\, *  * }  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
for finally arriving at
$$
f(x) = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   0 & {x <  - 1}  \\
   \pi  & { - 1 < x \leqslant 0}  \\
   {4\tan ^{ - 1} \left( {1/x} \right) - \pi } & {0 < x < 1}  \\
   {4\tan ^{ - 1} \left( {1/x} \right)} & {1 < x}  \\
 \end{array} } \right.
$$
where the critical points have been filled according to the limit values
of $f(x)$.

Comment: Same problem as the other answer. Wrong. Plot on WA: [OP's function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+acos((x%5E2-1)%2F(x%5E2%2B1))%2Batan((2x)%2F(x%5E2-1))+for+x+from+-2+to+3) and [yours](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+4arg(x%2Bi)+for+x+from+-2+to+3)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, oops, you are right, thanks for pointing out. The solution is ok for $1<x$, for other values the error comes from the difference $arctan$ and $arctan_{4 quadrants}$. I will correct.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, thanks to your warning, I could revise the last part : I will be glad to know your opinion.

Comment: Looks good now. I would have simplified $\arctan (1/x)$ using $\arctan (x)+\arctan (1/x)=\mathrm{sign}(x)\pi/2$, but it's not very important. Also, a little mistake remains: the function is not defined for $|x|=1$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, thanks again: corrected for $|x|=1$. With the simplification you suggest, we are getting the same result indicated by *robjohn*.